# It's obligatory to check more than one time visited nodes when using Dijkstra's algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, dijkstra, shortest-path

Me and my colleague are discussing a implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm. Here is the implementation using Python:

```
def dijkstra(self, origin, destination):
        """Use Dijkstra's algorithm to find the cheapest path."""

        routes = Heap()
        for neighbor in self.neighbors(origin):
            price = self.get_price(origin, neighbor)
            routes.push(Route(price=price, path=[origin, neighbor]))

        visited = set()
        visited.add(origin)

        while routes:

            # Find the nearest yet-to-visit airport
            price, path = routes.pop()
            airport = path[-1]
            if airport in visited:
                continue

            # We have arrived! Wo-hoo!
            if airport is destination:
                return price, path

            # Tentative distances to all the unvisited neighbors
            for neighbor in self.neighbors(airport):
                if neighbor not in visited:
                    # Total spent so far plus the price of getting there
                    new_price = price + self.get_price(airport, neighbor)
                    new_path  = path  + [neighbor]
                    routes.push(Route(new_price, new_path))

            visited.add(airport)

        return float('infinity')
```

The controversial line here is:

```
if neighbor not in visited:
```

My point is that this line must be replaced with something like

```
if neighbor not in visited or new_price < cost_so_far[neighbor]
```

In all the implementations that I found of the algorithm says that you must check for the case when you reach a node with a cost lower than the current cost of the node. For example, the **lines 17 and 18 of this pseudocode** from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm):

```
1  function Dijkstra(Graph, source):
2      dist[source] ← 0                                    // Initialization
3
4      create vertex set Q
5
6      for each vertex v in Graph:           
7          if v ≠ source
8              dist[v] ← INFINITY                          // Unknown distance from source to v
9              prev[v] ← UNDEFINED                         // Predecessor of v
10
11         Q.add_with_priority(v, dist[v])
12
13
14     while Q is not empty:                              // The main loop
15         u ← Q.extract_min()                            // Remove and return best vertex
16         for each neighbor v of u:                       // only v that is still in Q
17             alt = dist[u] + length(u, v) 
18             if alt < dist[v]
19                 dist[v] ← alt
20                 prev[v] ← u
21                 Q.decrease_priority(v, alt)
22
23     return dist[], prev[]
```

The question is: **Is my colleague's implementation correct or the code should be modified in order to check if you reach some neighbour with a price lower than the current one?**

Note: Here is the [source code](https://github.com/vterron/dijkstra/blob/master/dijkstra.py) of my colleague's implementation.

Comment: I guess you are almost there. Proof his algorithm incorrect by finding a graph where his algorithm provides a shortest path that is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the question is whether the line in your code

```
if neighbor not in visited:
```

can or must be replaced by

```
if neighbor not in visited or new_price < cost_so_far[neighbor]:
```

The answer is: can, yes; must, no.
Adding `new_price < cost_so_far[neighbor]` will not change anything in the flow of the algorithm, it will be false every time `neighbor not in visited` is false.

The reason is how Dijkstra's algorithm works.
Essentially, it builds a tree of shortest paths.
Whenever an `airport` is added to `visited`, it is considered to be in the tree: by this time, the algorithm has already found the shortest path to this `airport`.

Assume that at step `x`, we add a certain airport `A` to `visited`.
Further assume that at step `y > x`, `cost_so_far` to airport `A` decreased.
How could it decrease?
It would require that some `new_price = price + self.get_price(airport, neighbor)` is less than the `price` at step `y`.
Recall now that `routes` is a priority queue, so it supplies `price`s in non-decreasing order.
The edges of the graph are also non-negative (otherwise, Dijkstra's algorithm indeed produces a wrong result and is not applicable).
So, we arrive at a contradiction: the new `new_price` is at least the old price, but turned out to be less than that.

The source of confusion is perhaps that the main loop of the implementation considers some routes one-by-one.
Essentially, these routes correspond to edges of the graph.
So, there can be |E| routes, but only |V| of them will get accepted, all others will fail the condition `if airport in visited:  continue`.
If we implement the algorithm so that each iteration of the main loop adds exactly one `airport` to `visited` (exactly one vertex to the tree of shortest paths), the whole matter may become clearer.

Comment: Can you explain then why lines 17-18 in the pseudocode?

Comment: @Dargor They basically say "The best `dist[v]` can be constructed as, for some `u`, the best `dist[u]` plus `length (u, v)`". Indeed, any best path minus the last edge is the best path to the previous vertex: if there's any better path to the previous vertex, why not use that better path and then go by the same edge?

Comment: So what you are saying is that neighbor not in visited and new_price < cost_so_far[neighbor] are equivalent relations?

Comment: @Dargor You can maintain a priority queue with one entry per vertex in the graph, and then locate entries and decrease their priorities. Unfortunately, the means of locating an entry inside a priority queue are not present in standard libraries of common languages. (Still, you'd be fine with your own implementation, or using an ordered set instead of a priority queue.)

Comment: @Dargor Alternatively, you can just push each vertex to the priority queue multiple times, with possibly different distances to it. The smallest distance wins, all other (greater) distances are discarded later when the vertex is already in `visited`.

Comment: @Dargor _So what you are saying is that neighbor not in visited and new_price < cost_so_far[neighbor] are equivalent relations?_ No, what I am saying is when `neighbor` is in `visited`, the situation where `new_price < cost_so_far[neighbor]` can't happen, so it's irrelevant whether you check an always-false statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101236/discussion-between-gassa-and-dargor).